# Перевод кода при работе с map на java 9

Tags: java

Есть следующий код

```
private static Map<String, Integer> retryingPerevods = new HashMap<>();
String perevod = ....;
if (!retryingPerevods.containsKey(perevod)) {
    retryingPerevods.put(perevod, 1);
} else {
    retryingPerevods.put(perevod, retryingPerevods.get(perevod) + 1);
}
```

Все просто если есть определенный ключ в мапе, то кладем 1, если нет то инкрементируем и все равно кладем. Необходимо перевести его на java 9. Крутил с computeIfAbsent и другим, но пока не удалось его никак преобразовать, уменьшить. Помогите пожалуйста если не затруднит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
retryingPerevods.compute(perevod, (k, v) -> (v == null) ? 1 : ++v);
```

Comment: вопросик есть. compute - вычисление в обоих случаях computeIfAbsent и computeIfPresent, то есть поддерживает эти два случая?

Comment: Да, именно так.